# Visual Basic Rnd returns 5 every time

Tags: vb.net, random

***SOLVED***
The goal of this random function is to return a value which will be used to capitalize the corresponding line with that number, my issue is that it returns 5 every time, so something must be going wrong. Can anyone explain what I did wrong with this randomize function?

EDIT: I now get the error "randomize is a type, and cannot be used as an expression".

Here the piece of code: randomize is a type and cannot be used as an expression.

```
 Module randomize
   Sub Main()

     Dim line As String = ""
     Dim linenum As Integer = 1
         Randomize()
     Dim random as Integer 
         random = CInt(Int((7 * Rnd()) + 1))

             'If linenum=random the line is capitalized.
```

Comment: Rename your module. Now the compiler thinks that you want to call the module, not the built in `Randomize` function.

Comment: And, of course: http://www.xkcd.com/221/ ;)

Comment: @Guffa - I hadn't seen that one!  I lol'd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for `Rnd`, you need to call `Randomize` first to create a new seed.

Also, I'm not sure if it's a good idea naming your module after the function you need to call.

Comment: I get the error, "randomize is a type, and cannot be used as an expression". My code looks like this now (see edit):      Randomize()
                          random = CInt(Int((7 * Rnd()) + 1))

Comment: Like I said, rename your module.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
 Dim x As Integer
 Randomize()
 x = CInt(Int((7 * Rnd()) + 1))
```